# Is "Sorry for the inconveniences" the right expression?

Tags: word-usage

I know

> Sorry for the inconvenience

and

> Sorry for any inconveniences

are both commonly used, but is *"Sorry for the inconveniences"* considered *wrong*, even though it is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically, there is no rule that will tell you that you cannot use *inconveniences*, in the plural, that is. ***[Inconvenience](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inconvenience)*** can be a countable or uncountable noun. But it is so much [*less idiomatic*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20for%20the%20inconvenience%2C%20sorry%20for%20the%20inconveniences&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorry%20for%20the%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorry%20for%20the%20inconveniences%3B%2Cc0) that I don't see why you need to consider it.

If you really MUST use it, it may be more acceptable if you add *created*, or *caused*, or some sort of description of those particular inconveniences:

> Sorry for the inconveniences *created*/*that were caused in the process*/etc.

---

<sub>Note that for ***sorry for any inconveniences***, [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20for%20the%20inconvenience%2Csorry%20for%20the%20inconveniences%2C%20sorry%20for%20any%20inconvenieces&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorry%20for%20the%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorry%20for%20the%20inconveniences%3B%2Cc0) finds no instance.</sub>

Comment: Yes, that was my feeling, that the plural is only used when you add some modifiers or when you are talking about some specific, actual inconveniences. I asked simply because I'm not a native and I've seen other natives use the plural in this expression, which sounded wrong to me. It's nice to have Ngram confirm my intuitions, thanks for the tip.